# Select one of two register spaces in VHDL

Tags: fpga, vhdl

I want to create a system consisting of two register spaces (A and B, see the figure below). The purpose is to allow for instant configuration switching. When S=0, the registers in A will be select for writing (new configuration), and the registers in B will be selected for reading (running configuration). When S=1, opposite is true.

```
            +
            |
            |
    +-------v--------+ not(S)
    |  WRITE SELECT  <---+
    +----------------+
       |0        |1
       |         |
     +-v-+     +-v-+
     |   |     |   |
     | A |     | B |
     |   |     |   |
     +-+-+     +-+-+
       |         |
       |         |
    +--v---------v---+ S
    |  READ  SELECT  <---+
    +-------+--------+
            |
            |OUT
            v
```

My question is about how to code the read select in VHDL. Assuming only one configuration register:

```
signal S : integer range 0 to 1;
type slv_ary_t is array (integer range <>) of standard_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
signal reg_space : slv_ary_t(1 downto 0)
signal OUT : standard_logic_vector(31 downto 0);

begin
-- What is the difference between this:
OUT <= reg_space(S);
-- and this
OUT <= reg_space(0) when S=0 else reg_space(1);
```

My understanding right now is that this will result in the same hardware after synthesis. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes**, the two statements are equivalent.

Here's proof:

Consider this code

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity reg_select is
    Port ( clk : in  std_logic;
           sel : in  integer range 0 to 1;
           d   : in  std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
           eq  : out std_logic );
end reg_select;

architecture behavioral of reg_select is

    type slv_ary_t is array (0 to 1) of std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
    signal reg_space : slv_ary_t;

    signal qa : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
    signal qb : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
begin

    -- Write
    process(clk)
    begin
        if rising_edge(clk) then
            case sel is
                when 0 => reg_space(1) <= d;
                when 1 => reg_space(0) <= d;
            end case;
        end if;
    end process;

    -- Read
    qa <= reg_space(sel);
    qb <= reg_space(0) when sel=0 else reg_space(1);

    -- Compare
    eq <= '1' when qa=qb else '0';

end behavioral;
```

Here we use `qa` and `qb` to hold both of your read statements. Then signal `eq` is set if they are equivalent.

Without synthesis, the RTL schematic looks like this:
[image: RTL schematic]
The `sel` input signal selects the appropriate read/write registers, and the output reads are compared. If you look carefully, though, you can immediately see that both of the `qa` and `qb` selections are equivalent.

As further proof, look what happens post-synthesis:
[image: Post-synthesis]
The synthesizer eliminates all of the input signals, since they become irrelevant, and the output is forced to **1** (in a weird CARRY4 implementation). In other words, the synthesis tool identifies that the output `eq` does not require any of the inputs - since `eq` will be **1** irrespective of the input values (as shown in the sim):

[image: Sim]

*Note, you have a typo in your code: `standard_logic_vector` should be `std_logic_vector`*

Answer (score 0):

Both variants will consume the same amount of logic altough the synthesizer may route them differently.